# Unity Game crashing on some devices

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

In my testing, the game works good on my android 5.1 and ios 10.3.2 (iPhone 6S) devices.
But on my Apple reviewer's iPad Air 2 and iPhone 7 Plus, I get crash on game launch. I got the crashlogs and did symbolicate them, the crash log is:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ad39014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ae03264 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018acad9c4 abort + 140
3   truck                           0x000000010059afc0 _GLOBAL__I_a (VerifyiPhoneSplashScreen.cpp:0)
4   truck                           0x000000010059a2f4 VerifyiPhoneSplashScreen(std::string const&) (basic_string.h:238)
5   truck                           0x00000001005788a8 UnityInitApplicationNoGraphics (basic_string.h:280)
6   truck                           0x000000010003f718 -[UnityAppController application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (UnityAppController.mm:226)
7   UIKit                           0x0000000191eda204 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 380
8   UIKit                           0x00000001920e6738 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3452
9   UIKit                           0x00000001920ec1e0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1684
10  UIKit                           0x0000000192100d18 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3151 + 48
11  UIKit                           0x00000001920e9474 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
12  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018d8e7884 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
13  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018d8e76f0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176
14  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018d8e7aa0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bced42c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bcecd9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bcea9a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bc1ada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
19  UIKit                           0x0000000191ed3384 -[UIApplication _run] + 652
20  UIKit                           0x0000000191ece058 UIApplicationMain + 208
21  truck                           0x00000001000322b4 main (main.mm:39)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018ac2959c start + 4
```

Please see and let me know if any way to find out the root cause of crash. To me it looks like game doesn't go beyond the splash screen but what is the cause of it not failing on my end.

Comment: Did you use custom splash screen?

Comment: If you use custom splash screen and you don't have the iOS license, you will encounter the crash ( I know the crash is awkward ). See [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/636918/verifyiphonesplashscreen-causing-crash-on-launch-o.html)

Comment: @Raptor I have free version of Unity, so I should set splash screen as Default or None in Unity player settings?

Comment: Yes, correct. Leave it as default will be fine (by choosing Default, an Unity logo will be displayed in splash screen).